# Solve $I = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{\frac{\cos x}{\cos x + \sin x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}g(x)\,dx = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{\frac{\cos x}{\cos x + \sin x}}\,dx$$

This is part of a 3-part exercise where I was given $f, g:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb R \,\,\, $, $\,\,f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x} \,\,\,$ , $\,\,g(x)=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x} $

And these are the two things that I had to prove previously:

$(1)$ $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\big({f(x)+g(x)\big)}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$
$(2)$ $h:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb R\,\,\, $,  $\,\,h(x)=\ln(\sin x + \cos x)$ is a primitive of $g-f$

I am sure that I need to use one or both of the relations above to solve this integral but I can't figure it out. I can see that $(1)$ is equivalent to $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}{g(x)} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}f(x) \, dx $

I tried to solve the integral using u-sub and integration by parts and also tried to rewrite the integral using trigonometric identities but I had no succes so I am certain we need to make use of $(1)$ or/and $(2)$.

Comment: Hint $$\int_{a}^b f(x) dx = \int_{a}^b f(b + a - x) dx$$

Comment: You've $I+J = \cdots $ and $I-J = \cdots $ so that $(I+J)+(I-J) = \cdots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$.

Note that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx = [\ln(\sin(x)+\cos(x))]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=0$.

Hence $I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$.

Next up,

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Hence $2I = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $I = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: This certainly makes the problem more complicated than it needs to be, since there is no need to find any antiderivatives.

Comment: this is just what I saw when I looked at the problem, there is no strategy as such.

Comment: And still it makes the problem appear more complicated than it is.

Comment: this is an absurdly simple proof, I wrote it in 30 seconds

Comment: Nonetheless there's a simpler way.

Comment: @MichaelHardy. This is an exercise in a 12th grade high school book. It might seem harder to you to solve this way but I looked at your answer and that substitution is totally out of reach for anyone in the 12th grade.

Comment: @RaduGabriel : It is nonsense to say my solution is out of reach to all 12th-graders. It is a substitution of the kind taught to 12th-graders. I did things like that when I was in 12th-grade. What _typical_ 12th-graders do is that they're in it for grades or because someone pressured them to be there---both ignoble reasons; people like that don't count in this.

Comment: have to agree with Michael on this one, substitutions of this kind are a great tool

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I understand why you think that. High school might be different in US, I guess you'll have to trust me that this answer is easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is the same as solutions above but with more details.

Start with $x\to \frac{\pi}{2}-x$ to have

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}\ dx=-\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\ dx$$

Add the integral to both sides,

$$\Longrightarrow I+I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\Longrightarrow I=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \frac{\cos x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, dx = \frac{\sin u}{ \cos u + \sin u} (-du) \\[12pt]
\text{where } & u = \frac \pi 2 - x, \\[6pt]
\text{ so that } & \cos x = \sin u \text{ and } \sin x = \cos u.
\end{align}
And as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi,$ $u$ goes from $\pi$ to $0.$

So the integrals of of $f$ and $g$ are equal to each other.

Comment: +1 for simplicity Michael

Answer (score 0):

You have found the primitive of $g - f$, and the primitive of $g + f = 1$ is obvious. Now write it as follows:
$$
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} g(x) \; \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} (g(x) + f(x)) \; \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} (g(x) - f(x)) \; \mathrm{d}x
$$